# post json request in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, jersey

I have a mySQL database, an iPhone client and a RESTful Web Service(using jersey) as an intermediate layer between them. I connected successfully to the database and implemented a `GET` Request. I have problem to `POST` to it.

In this way I prepare JSON to transfer:

```
NSDate *date = self.pickerView.date;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter release];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"mail",@"password",@"mobil", @"birth", @"city" , nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:name.text, mail.text, password.text, mobil.text, stringFromDate, city.text, nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];


NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

I tried two ways to `POST`, but non of them was successful.

**1)** using JSON NSString:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.100:8080/rest/login/post"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

   NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

**2)** using NSData:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.100:8080/rest/login/post"]];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSURLConnection * myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

I have this method also in my codes:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSMutableData *d = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    [d appendData:data];
    NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", a);
}
```

I got this error in Console:

```
    Data: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 - Error report</title><style><!--
H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-
size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-
color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-
serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-
family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-
family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-
family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color :
 black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status
 406 - Not Acceptable</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p>
<b>message</b> <u>Not Acceptable</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The resource identified by 
this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable 
according to the request "accept" headers (Not Acceptable).</u></p><HR size="1" 
noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.23</h3></body></html>
```

I appreciate for any help.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. What exactly is going wrong here? Are you seeing any errors? Not seeing the request hit the server? Not getting a response? Crashing?

Comment: I added the error message at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response says, that it doenst like this

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

So it doenst offer to respond with json.

The documentation of the web service should list all possible values.

You may want to try

```
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Or reconfigure tomcat to accept json as response format.

Comment: `{"name":"jkkh","password":"kjh","mobil":"kjh","birth":"1981-01-01","city":"kjhkj","mail":"kjhh"}`

Comment: This the print of json string in the client. Do you think anything is wrong with it?

Comment: this is, what you want to send to the server. and it is probably ok. but you tell the tomcat, that the client is accepting json, but tomcat seems to be unable to response with json

Comment: you should try out with some rest debugging tools, what is a valid setting. I use restclient for mac. but also curl and other commandline tools can do this.

Comment: I transfer JSON with my Android application and Web Service perfectly works. The problem is here.

Comment: Also easily I tested my Service with Jersey Client and `POST` which works.

Comment: as I said: the sending seems to be ok, but your client is telling the server, that it would accept json only. and the server doesnt like that.